# Bind GridView from Background Thread

Tags: asp.net, ajax, binding, background-thread

I've built a reporting function which will call several Stored Procedures before binding the final query to a `GridView` which then has several processes in the `GridView_DataBound` event before displaying the results on the page.

The overall process can take up to 1 minute to complete.

Rather than the user having to wait this long before a response, is there a way I can run this script in a background thread and then bind somehow using AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't because when the HTML is rendered to the browser, your other Thread may still be working on getting the data.

You can do something like this if you do the databinding strictly client-side.